# Length of a string (var)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried without success to get the length of the "time" (hours, value is 1-24):

```
var time2 = Math.floor(startTimeT);
```

Try 1:

```
var startTimeTC1L = time2.length;
```

Try 2:

```
var startTimeTC1L = time2.toString().length;
alert(startTimeTC1L);
```

I just want to get a "1" or "2" as returned value (0-9 == 1, 10-24 == 2), but it's not working?

Comment: What is the value of `startTimeT`?

Comment: I dont exactly know what you are trying to achieve, but can you not consider doing this -  `variable < 10` and `variable > 10 and < 24` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use, Assuming `startTimeT` is a number. Converts to string then simply use lenght property

```js
var startTimeT = 15;
var strVar = startTimeT+''; //Convert to string
var length = strVar.length;
alert(length)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd try works,
here http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/144ex55c/

Here is another much simple approach http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/144ex55c/1/

because you just want to get 1 or 2 you can simply use

```
    var time2 = Math.floor(24);
alert(time2);
if(time2<10)
{
    startTimeTC1L=1;  
}
else{
      startTimeTC1L=2; 
}

alert(startTimeTC1L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as

```
var startTimeT = 15554;
var len = startTimeT.toString().length;
alert(len)
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sotwuuom/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working with date, how about something like this:

Paste it in firebug's console or use nodejs on the command line.

```
var hours = ""+(new Date()).getHours(); 
hours[0] === "0" ? console.log(1) : console.log(hours.length)
```

I hope it helps.